# Absolute centering does not work in FF

Tags: css

I want to absolute a div the following way, but for some reason firefox is pushing the div to the very top, so it is centered horizontally, but vertically it is top. Chrome works fine

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="login">
            <div id="header">ict <span class="redText">recruit</span></div>
            <div id="wrapper">

                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="loginBox">
                        <div class="control-group" id="Div1">

                            <div class="controls">
                                <label class="control-label" for="firstName1">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group" id="firstName1g">
                            <label class="control-label" for="firstName1">Password</label>                
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#login{
    position: relative;

    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#header {
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #dc0000;
    font-family: Leelawadee, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.redText {
    color: rgb(220,0,0);
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    text-align: left;
}
div.page-header h1 {
    font-family: Leelawadee, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #dc0000;
}
#loginBox {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

}
```

Comment: I don't see elements with `absolute` position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, its a bad idea to use negative margins...particularly when they're effecting a major structural element in the DOM.  I would recommend you take a different approach to centering your `#wrapper` div like the one i've made in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Uwsxu/2/

in short, remove your negative margins and your `left:50%` and `top:50%`

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: how would I vertical align the wrapper div then relative to the page/viewport?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the negative margins on your wrapper. Set the position to absolute. Adjust the top and left percentages.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pkzt3/3/)

***CSS***

```
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: absolute;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 30%;
   text-align: left;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Like Morpheus said: You do not have the position on the wrapper as absolute.

If you want to use this method:

```
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
```

then the position should be absolute or fixed, not relative.

So I suggest the following for centering the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 150px; (+ the 50px for the header, since it is relative to the header as well)
    text-align: left;
}
```